# Cannot set title and alt attributes in my img using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the Google Image Search API, and largely copied this code, which builds the search results in my page.

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    // For each result write it's title and image to the screen
    var result = results[i];
    var linkContainer = document.createElement('div');

    var title = document.createElement('div');
    // We use titleNoFormatting so that no HTML tags are left in the title
    title.innerHTML = result.titleNoFormatting;

    var newImg = document.createElement('img');

    newImg.src = result.tbUrl;
    newImg.className = 'googleSearchResult';
    newImg.title = 'newTitle';
    newImg.alt = 'newAlt';

    var newLink = document.createElement('a');
    newLink.href = "temp_url";              

    newLink.appendChild(newImg);
    contentDiv.appendChild(newLink);
}
```

In the following lines,

```
newImg.src = result.tbUrl;
newImg.className = 'googleSearchResult';
newImg.title = 'newTitle';
newImg.alt = 'newAlt';
```

the first two, which set the image src and class, work fine, but the second two, which should set the title and alt of the image, don't work at all. Can anyone see why this would be happening? Thanks for reading.

EDIT:
Here is the HTML when inspected in Firefox through Firebug:

```
<img alt="" src="http://images.google.com/images?q=tbn:_HZix2CrLSLSOM::bestonlinetvseries.com/deadwood/deadwood_s01.jpg" class="googleSearchResult">
```

Here is the HTML when inspected in Google Chrome

```
<img alt src="http://images.google.com/images?q=tbn:_HZix2CrLSLSOM::bestonlinetvseries.com/deadwood/deadwood_s01.jpg" class="googleSearchResult">
```

EDIT: 
What I am trying to do here is store an extra bit of data in the HTML for the image, to be used in a jQuery plugin later. If anyone can suggest an alternative way to do this, that would be great as well.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it didn't seem to help. Actually it was not totally correct as a DOM image element has indeed a property `alt`. Sorry for that.

Comment: Never use `getAttribute`/`setAttribute` on HTML documents. It's less readable than the plain property access method, and many attributes are buggy in IE.

Comment: If you're just trying to store data associated with the image for later use you could use jQuery's `data` method: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: @Richard M: Thanks for your answer, this is what I was looking for. If you submit an answer, I'll give you the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your last edit: if you're just trying to store data associated with an image for later use you could use jQuery's [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem lies elsewhere.  Consider [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/sCuBf/1/), which works fine in the browsers I've tested (Firefox, Chrome, IE):

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.title="Hello";
img.alt="alt Hello";
img.src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/sprites.png";
link.appendChild(img);
document.body.appendChild(link);

alert(img.getAttribute("alt"));
alert(img.getAttribute("title"));
```

I would recommend checking to see if anything might be in front of the link/img element, as this would stop a tooltip from appearing on hover.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really can't work out what I'm doing wrong. I'm inspecting the element in Firebug, and it says alt="" and has no mention of title at all.

Comment: @ben: is the same true in other browsers? Google Chrome has an inspector (Ctrl+Shift+I), IE has developer tools (F12).

Comment: I've edited the original question to show the output from the Google Chrome inspector

Comment: @ben: is it possible the code in the question is a simplified version of your actual code? Clearly, you're not doing much different to my working code, so it might be a good idea to post a link to the site where you have this set up.  A web debugging expert might be able to solve it for you in no time :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
img.setAttribute('title', 'someTitle');
```

Appearantly, there's a difference between 'properties' and 'attributes' in DOM scripting.